# Clonezilla installation - Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, backup, clonezilla

I'm trying to install clonezilla, but I got an error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
clonezilla is already the newest version (3.21.13-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up clonezilla (3.21.13-1) ...
ln: target '/opt/' is not a directory: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package clonezilla (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 clonezilla
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could anyone be able to tell what could I do to fix this problem?

**P.S.** I'm using Ubuntu gnome 16.10.

Comment: `target '/opt/' is not a directory: No such file or directory` - have you deleted your `/opt` directory at some point?

Comment: Perhaps, the /opt does not exist and the post-install script is buggy. You may have to  ̀mkdir` /opt directory and retry installation.

Comment: it works pretty well @steeldriver, thanks